# How to download and display pdf

Tags: html, web

I want to a create a button through which we can open a pdf in a viewer and at the same time the pdf get downloaded.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsPDF.
Please refer the following sample,

```
https://www.programering.com/a/MDMyczNwATE.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can done it with javascript

```
var file_path = 'host/path/file.ext';
var a = document.createElement('A');
a.href = file_path;
a.download = file_path.substr(file_path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```